# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication sign in as different user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I have been searching all day and I can't find a solution to this.

I am using windows authentication for an intranet application. I want to have the ability to click a link and sign in as a different user, similar to the option in SharePoint.

I have seen many proposed solutions on SO based on .net but none MVC specific.

I have come across HttpUnauthorizedResult

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

which forces the user to login but I don't believe you can redirect after logging in.

I have also tried

```
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

After three attempts I get an HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

This article is the most detailed I have found, however it is not specifically for mvc and my attempts to modify it have failed.

http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825

Has anyone got this to work or can you point me in the right direction.

I am interested in a cross browser solution as some of our users are on iPads, etc.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Did you found any solution for this ? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up removing the link to avoid confusion from users.

Comment: Why not store the referrer into tempdata before returning the unauthorized result. Once logged in, return a redirectresult to your tempdata url.

Answer (score 3):

My resolution to this problem is to create a "SignInAsDifferentUser" public method (action) and create a session variable to indicate whether I have previously visited this method or not. The first visit will set a session variable (IsEntered) to true and return HttpUnauthorizedResult(). Once new credentials entered by the user, you will come back to this method. But the session is already set to true. So, you will be redirected to Index method. I hope this helps.

```
public ActionResult SignInAsDifferentUser()
{

        if ((bool)(Session["IsEntered"] ?? false))
        {
            // already entered...
            Session["IsEntered"] = false;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["IsEntered"] = true;                
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do this in classic ASP.net with web forms. I'd imagine the same would work in MVC. I had to create a Active Directory library to log in as an 'Interactive' user with the web site set to identity impersonate. You'll need to access Win32 lib calls to do so. If you're still interested I can build a sample in Codeplex or something.